# Matplotlib live data animation runs out of memory

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ram

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to plot live data from serial, but eventually run out of memory. I'm not sure if/how I can close the figure, but still have a live data display.

Would it be possible to create and close a new figure with every animate?

My code at the moment:

```
import serial
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') #comment out for debugging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import gc

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()

xs = []
ysAC = []
ysDC = []

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.flush()

# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ysAC, ysDC):

  values = getValues()

  wAC = values[1]
  wDC = values[2]
 
  # Add x and y to lists
  xs.append(i)
  ysAC.append(wAC)
  ysDC.append(wDC)

  # Limit x and y lists to 10 items
  xs = ['T-9','T-8','T-7','T-6','T-5','T-4','T-3','T-2','T-1','Now'] 
  ysDC = ysDC[-10:]
  ysAC = ysAC[-10:]

  # Draw x and y lists
  axRT1.clear()   
    
  if len(ysDC) == 10:
    lineAC, = axRT1.plot(xs, ysAC, 'b:', label='Mains', linewidth = 4)
    lineDC, = axRT1.plot(xs, ysDC, 'g--', label='Solar', linewidth = 4)
    
  gc.collect()
  #fig.clf()
  #plt.close()

def getValues():
  
  if ser.in_waiting > 0:
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()   
    return list(line.split(","))  

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ysAC, ysDC), interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Don’t plot each time. Change the x and y data of the existing plot.

Comment: @JodyKlymak thank you. I can't figure out why set_data returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Answer (score 0):

The crude way of clearing the plots marked below fixed it for me:

```
import time
import serial
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') #comment out for debugging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os.path as path
import re
import gc
import os

count = 0

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
hFont = {'fontname':'sans-serif', 'weight':'bold', 'size':'12'}

xs = ['T-9','T-8','T-7','T-6','T-5','T-4','T-3','T-2','T-1','Now'] 
ysTemp = []
ysAC = []
ysDC = []

axRT1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
axRT2 = axRT1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
#Draw x and y lists
axRT1.clear()   
axRT2.clear()
axRT1.set_ylim([0, 4])
axRT2.set_ylim([10, 70])

axRT1.set_ylabel('Power Consumption kW', **hFont)
axRT2.set_ylabel('Temperature C', **hFont)
axRT1.set_xlabel('Seconds', **hFont)
axRT1.set_title('Power Consumption and Temperature - Real Time', **hFont)
lineTemp, = axRT2.plot([], [], 'r', label='Temp', linewidth = 4)
lineAC, = axRT1.plot([], [], 'b:', label='Mains', linewidth = 4)
lineDC, = axRT1.plot([], [], 'g--', label='Solar', linewidth = 4)
fig.legend([lineAC, lineDC,lineTemp], ['Mains', 'Solar', 'Temp'], fontsize=20)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.flush()

# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ysTemp, ysAC, ysDC):

  values = getValues()

  if values != 0:
    temp_c = Decimal(re.search(r'\d+',values[3]).group())
    if temp_c < 0: temp_c = 0
    wAC = round(Decimal(re.search(r'\d+', values[1]).group())/1000, 2)
    if wAC < 0.35: wAC = 0
    aDC = float(re.search(r'\d+', values[2]).group()) #remove characters
    vDC = float(re.search(r'\d+', values[4][:5]).group()) #remove characters
    wDC = aDC * vDC
    wDC = round(abs(Decimal(wDC))/1000, 2)


    # Add x and y to lists
    ysTemp.append(temp_c)
    ysAC.append(wAC)
    ysDC.append(wDC)

    # Limit x and y lists to 10 items
    ysTemp = ysTemp[-10:]
    ysDC = ysDC[-10:]
    ysAC = ysAC[-10:]

    if len(ysTemp) == 10:
      axRT2.lines = [] #This crude way of clearing the plots worked
      axRT1.lines =[] #This crude way of clearing the plots worked
      lineTemp, = axRT2.plot(xs, ysTemp, 'r', label='Temp', linewidth = 4)
      lineAC, = axRT1.plot(xs, ysAC, 'b:', label='Mains', linewidth = 4)
      lineDC, = axRT1.plot(xs, ysDC, 'g--', label='Solar', linewidth = 4)



def getValues():

  measureList = 0

  if ser.in_waiting > 0:
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(line)

    if line.count(',') == 4:
      measureList = list(line.split(","))  

  return measureList

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ysTemp, ysAC, ysDC), interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```